# Certificate Error - Navigation Blocked

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I'm receiving a certificate error on a pc that was recently updated to Windows 8.1 on our company network when attempting to access an intranet site. This is to be expected, since the certificate is self-signed and is not specific to the site's address. **However, I do not see the "Continue to this website" option, which prevents me from accessing the site entirely
.**

I have tried fiddling with time, reducing the new key length restriction (even though the key in question is 2048), and using fiddler to check the errors (only the expected RemoteCertificateNameMismatch).

Is there a new feature in IE11 or Windows 8.1 - aside from the new key length restriction - that would prevent me from visiting a site? If so, how do I turn this off? I would use another browser, but unfortunately Microsoft's App Controller only works in IE...

Comment: You can try to add the intranet URL to "Trusted Zone" and reduce down the Security Level for that zone, and see if that helps.

Comment: Provided you own the certificate the simplest solution would be to place it in the Certificate Store.  IE11 isn't the only browser that would complain the certificate is invalid.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not the complaint that's the problem, it's the fact that I can't continue to the website.

Comment: @Darius I've tried turning down the intranet security level and adding the site to trusted sites (with and without the https requirement checked).

Comment: @Koogle - Have you placed the certificate into the certificate store?

Comment: @Ramhound Looks like that opened up the option to continue. Do you know why this is? Feel free to add your solution as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Koogle - The simplest explaination is that Windows had no idea what to do with the certificate, until you told it, that the certificate while invalid could be trusted.  I don't understand the certifcate store within Windows enough to explain the percise reason in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound)'s comment lead me to the only working solution for untrusted certificates, which was to add the certificate to the certificate store. If your certificate is trusted and less than 1024 bits, then [erict](https://superuser.com/a/926182/278979)'s answer will be more relevant.

Comment: The certificate to access my router over https was also untrusted -- and I presumably 512 bytes.  Adding the above allowed me to access the router.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Internet Explorer blocks all certificates that are less than 1024 bits.  I found [this article](http://blog.oracle48.nl/internet-explorer-10-continue-to-this-website-option-missing/) which says to open an admin command prompt to execute the following

```
certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512
```

This allows 512-bit certs, by enabling the link "Continue to this website".

Of course this weakens your machine's security, so you might want to undo after by running in the admin command box:

```
certutil -delreg chain\MinRsaPubKeyBitLength
```

Comment: This does in fact work for certificates less than 1024 bits, but the original question revolved around an untrusted certificate of 2048 bit length.

Comment: Oops, missed that.

Comment: No worries. I up-voted your answer anyways, since it may be relevant to anyone viewing this question.